# Framework7 - SearchBar close keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, searchbar, html-framework-7

I am trying to create a custom search `searchBar` element using framework7. The code I have so far works and when the search button is pressed the app is redirected  to another page. The problem I have is that when the app opens the page the keyboard remains open.

Is there a way to force the keyboard to close when the button `Search` is pressed?
HTML:

```
<form class="searchbar">
    <div class="searchbar-input">
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search" style=" background-image: url(img/search.png);">
        <a href="#" class="searchbar-clear"></a>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS

```
 $$('.searchbar').on("search", function (e) {
            //close the keyboard 
            mainView.router.load({
                url: 'productlist.html'
            });
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

disable the searchbar before loading new page